# Expand dates and times in data frame with missing for each parameter

Tags: r

I have the following data set:

```
Date<-c("2013-01-01 02:00:00","2013-01-02 02:00:00","2013-01-03 02:00:00","2013-01-01 02:00:00","2013-01-02 02:00:00","2013-01-03 02:00:00")
Parameter<-c("Par1","Par1","Par1","Par2","Par2","Par2")
conc<-c(1,4,3,2,6,5)
obs<-data.frame(Date,Parameter,conc)
obs$Date<-as.POSIXct(obs$Date)
obs$Parameter<-as.factor(obs$Parameter)
obs$conc<-as.numeric(obs$conc)
```

For each day between 2013-01-01 and 2013-01-03 there was an observation made at 02:00:00 hours for each of the 2 parameters. I will need to expand this data set to full 24-hour days and also take the parameter and value for each missing time per each day. I tried it with creating a new data.frame with all dates and times between 2013-01-01 and 2013-01-03 and then merging it with the obs data frame but I cannot figure out how to use each parameter name and observation value for the missing dates and times. 
The result should look like this:

```
Date                       Parameter conc
2013-01-01 00:00:00      Par1        1
2013-01-01 01:00:00      Par1        1
2013-01-01 02:00:00      Par1        1
.
. 
.
2013-01-01 23:00:00      Par1        1
2013-01-02 00:00:00      Par1        4
2013-01-02 01:00:00      Par1        4  
2013-01-02 02:00:00      Par1        4
.
.
.
2013-01-02 23:00:00      Par1        4   
2013-01-03 00:00:00      Par1        3
2013-01-03 01:00:00      Par1        3
2013-01-03 02:00:00      Par1        3
.
.
.
2013-01-03 23:00:00      Par1        3
2013-01-01 00:00:00      Par2        2
2013-01-01 01:00:00      Par2        2
2013-01-01 02:00:00      Par2        2
.
.
.
2013-01-01 23:00:00      Par2        2
2013-01-02 00:00:00      Par2        6
2013-01-02 01:00:00      Par2        6   
2013-01-02 02:00:00      Par2        6
.
.
.
2013-01-02 23:00:00      Par2        6
2013-01-03 00:00:00      Par2        5
2013-01-03 01:00:00      Par2        5
2013-01-03 02:00:00      Par2        5
.
.
.
2013-01-03 23:00:00      Par2        5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative answer:

```
new.Date <- matrix(sapply(obs$Date,function(t) t + as.difftime(-2:21,units = "hours")),ncol=1)
new.Par  <- matrix(sapply(obs$Parameter,function(x)rep(x,24)),ncol=1)
new.conc <- matrix(sapply(obs$conc,function(x)rep(x,24)),ncol=1)

newData <- data.frame(
  Date      = as.POSIXct(new.Date, origin = "1970-01-01"),
  Parameter = new.Par,
  new.conc  = new.conc
```

)

Comment: I can see that this code depends on the fact that the observation was made at 02:00:00. Would there be an alternative code if the observation wasn´t on a fixed time but changes between the days and parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is exactly what you ment since the result you try to get has eighter some tipos in it or does not make sense to me, but have a look at this:

```
expDate <- function(startTime,t_par,t_conc){
  if(is.character(startTime)){
    startTime <- as.POSIXct(startTime,origin= "1970-01-01")
  }

  nExp <- 24
  timeExpand <- as.difftime(0:nExp,units="hours")
  returnDF <- data.frame(
    Date      = startTime + timeExpand,
    Parameter = rep(t_par,nExp+1),
    conc      = rep(t_conc,nExp+1)
  )
  return(returnDF)
}

tempData <- apply(obs,1,function(x) expDate(x[1],x[2],x[3]))
newData <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(tempData)){
  newData <- rbind(newData,tempData[[i]])
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result is somewhat different of what I need. I checked my example and couldn´t find any typos. What I would need the script to do is just expand the existing df "ops" by expanding each day from 00:00:00 hours to 23:00:00 while duplicating the existing parameter name and value for the added times for each day, respectively.

Comment: ok, but in your question the parameter and conc column aren't not just duplicates...

Comment: Sorry, I realised that the conc vector had the wrong numbers after conversion from character to numeric. I updated my example. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: I addapted the answer so it fits more to what you are looking for.